# Outlook Python Restrict between year to year

Tags: python, outlook, mapi

I have been trying to `Restrict` the mails that i read from outlook using `Python MAPI` like as follows:

```
year1 = date(2019,1,1)
year2 = date(2020,1,1)

.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + year1.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')+"'" and "[ReceivedTime] >= '" + year1.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')+"'")
```

It doesn't throw any error but doesn't work either.
Please Help !

Comment: Can you post compete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you wanted to get items between two dates:

```
.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + year1.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')+"' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" + year2.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')+"'")
```

Although dates and times are typically stored with a Date format, the Find and Restrict methods require that the date and time be converted to a string representation. For example, in VBA to make sure that the date is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the `Format` function.

Read more about the `Restrict` method in the [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/) article.

Comment: Thnaks @Eugene, I was in fact waiting for you to reply.

Comment: Another error that has been throwing up is : `com_error: (-2147467262, 'No such interface supported', None, None)`

Comment: I have a for loop with : x.SenderName, x.receivedtime etc , all these throw the same error.

Comment: So,to summarize, I want all the details (SenderName, Subject, ReceivedTime etc) for a fixed period of time(say 2019 to 2020). The above `Restrict` works fine (I checked with a loop counter over x.Subject) but the other features are throwing the above error.

Comment: The folder may contain different item types, not all of them have the same properties.

Comment: That might be correct, so what to do in that case ?

Comment: I was actually trying to read my office inbox, it does have different types of emails. But not really sure if item types are different. Generally its text, pictures etc

Comment: In the loop, before accessing any properties you need to check the item's type.

Comment: Not really sure how to check the `type` but why & how does Subject work and SenderName doesn't ?